# H2 DB runscript error

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I have the following line in the H2 datasource configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test_db;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test_db;\\;RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/sql/populate.sql'\\;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
</bean>
```

When I run it, i get the following error:

```
SQL state [90046];error code [90046]; URL format error; must be "jdbc:h2:{ {.|mem:}[name] | [file:]fileName | {tcp|ssl}:[//]server[:port][,server2[:port]]/name }[;key=value...]"
 but is "jdbc:h2:mem:test_db" [90046-160]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc
.JdbcSQLException: URL format error; must be "jdbc:h2:{ {.|mem:}[name] | [file:]
fileName | {tcp|ssl}:[//]server[:port][,server2[:port]]/name }[;key=value...]" b
ut is "jdbc:h2:mem:test_db" [90046-160]
```

which I don't understand, can someone see the error here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test_db;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test_db\;RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/sql/populate.sql';DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably breaking the ;key=value pattern. You have to escape the semicolon. The semicolon after "test_db" isn't escaped. Try to leave it out.

```
jdbc:h2:mem:test_db;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test_db\;RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/sql/populate.sql';DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

Comment: Only one backslash (I made the same mistake). Not sure how to avoid this "escaping hell"...